# Terraform oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request │ Response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

this is my file main.tf

```
data "google_compute_image" "my-image" {
  name    = "my-image-bk"
  project = "my-proyect"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "my-instance" {
  name = "instance-live"
  #machine_type = "e2-custom-2-2096"
  machine_type   = "e2-small"
  zone           = var.zone
  can_ip_forward = false
  description    = ""


  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = data.google_compute_image.my-image.self_link
      type  = "pd-ssd"
      size  = "100"
    }
  }
 
   
  network_interface {
    #network = google_compute_network.my-network.id
    #subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.subnet-my.id        
    network    = "default"
    network_ip = "10.150.0.10"
    access_config {
    }
  }

  service_account {
    scopes = ["userinfo-email", "compute-ro", "storage-ro"]
  }
}
```

When exec terraform plan..... terraform launch this error:

> Error: error retrieving image information: Get
> "https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/global/images/my-image?alt=json&prettyPrint=false":
> oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request Response:
> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}

of course, the image "my-image" exists in the project my-project, i check this with the command :

```
gcloud compute images list --project my-project
```

any idea?

**My Platform:**
OS: windows 11, Terraform: 0.13 and 1.3.6... same error, provider: GCP